# Data marked as dirty even though it hasn't changed

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Even though I'm affecting the same value to an existing field, it's being marked as dirty.

Note: The reason for direct assignment of values is because I'm importing data from an Excel file and programmatically updating rows where needed.

```
$request = $this->Requests->get(123);
//existing field is "ABC123"
$request->field = 'ABC123';
//field will be set as dirty, even if the content is the same
debug($request->getDirty());
```

Output:

```
[
(int) 0 => 'field',
]
```

Is there built-in functionality that would compare the data and not mark the field as dirty as the data didn't change? Perhaps there's an existing plugin?

Otherwise, it probably involves writing a behavior overriding `beforeSave` that does all of this?

**Solution:**

```
$patch = ['field' => 'ABC123'];
$request = $this->Requests->patchEntity($request, $patch);
//isDirty() is false!
```

Comment: Just use `patchEntity` instead of direct assignment.

Comment: @GregSchmidt This example is from going through an excel file and programmatically updating rows (in some cases, involving some logic), which explains the direct assignment.

Comment: `$this->Requests->patchEntity($request, ['field' => 'ABC123'])` should work fine? Or build up an array of updates to the entity from the CSV and patch them all at once? I don't see why (apart from extra keystrokes) patching is necessarily an unavailable alternative to direct assignment.

Comment: @gregSchmidt it's not unavailable, I wasn't aware of this being an option. I'm using PHPSpreadsheet to import, which gives me an indexed array to work with. So, build a custom array that matches my fields and patch it? By patching, it won't mark the fields that don't change as dirty?

Comment: @GregSchmidth I tested it out and it works! See solution added. If you put a blurb talking about this, I'll accept as answer and you can get some points out of it.